# EnsureUser throws The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again

Tags: 2010, security, active-directory

I have this code:

The EnsureUser Line is throwing me that exception, any idea?

The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

```
 samAccountNames = GetSamAccountNamesToRemove(FindUsernames(membergroup), ppePeople2.GetSamAccountNames());

                        try
                        {

                            // Get the distinguished name for the usernames that should be removed from the (Member) AD Group and remove from the group
                            foreach (string username in samAccountNames)
                            {
                                string userdn = GetObjectDistinguishedName("user", username);

                                RemoveFromGroup(userdn, groupdn);

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                                {
                                    SPUser user = UpdateCurrentweb.EnsureUser(domain + "\\" + username);
                                    string group = "Member";
                                    int UserListID = UserAccessID(WorkspaceAccessList, user.Name, group);

                                    SPListItem item = WorkspaceAccessList.GetItemById(UserListID);
                                    UpdateCurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    item.Delete();
                                    UpdateCurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this with elevated permissions? http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the

```
UpdateCurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

up before the call to EnsureUser. Maybe even further out depending on what RemoveFromGroup does.
There is no need to set it to false unless it's something like SPContext.Current.Web which is passed to other components